# $.each function to add return to an external variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I have an Array of Strings, which i process with this function:

```
$.each(lines, processLine);
```

processLine function returns another string, but i need to combine the strings into one result. The main problem is that i don't want the processLine function to refer to the external variable (named css), it just has to return the result, and do the combination externally. So here's what i did:

```
var css = '';
css += $.each(lines, processLine);
```

But css variable ends up with the combinations of the original Arrays elements (not processed), don't know why...

Comment: $.map might end up being a better option

Comment: The simplest would be to remove the `css += ` and put it at the end of `processLine`.

Comment: Well, `.each` return nothing. May we see what is `processLine`?

Comment: $.map(lines, processLine);
var result = lines.join(',');

Comment: Inside callback(processLine) you have to do the appending..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) *iterates*, [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) *projects*. Since you want to *project* values from your lines, you should use `$.map()`:

```
var css = $.map(lines, processLine).join("");
```

The function passed to `$.map()` is invoked for each item in the array with two arguments: the item itself and its index. Since `processLine()` takes a line as its first and only argument, we can pass that function directly instead of using an anonymous function as an intermediate.

From there, [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) will build a string from our projected array. Passing the empty string as a separator results in simple concatenation.

*EDIT:* If `processLine()` does not take a single `line` argument, then my reasoning above is incorrect and you have to write something like:

```
var css = $.map(lines, function(line, index) {
    return processLine(index, line);
}).join("");
```

Comment: sorry for the misscomunication, the processLine takes index and line variables, i think yours is the right answer but could you please give me the old example?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can implement a function like this:

```
function processLines(lines) {
  var resultCss = '';
  $.each (lines, function() { resultCss += processLine(this) });
  return resultCss;
}

var css = processLines(yourLines);
```